# CLI tool to validate schema of YAML file?

Tags: validation, yaml, schema

Say I have a YAML file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaihendry/days/main/template.yml
with an accompanying schema:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awslabs/goformation/master/schema/sam.schema.json

What tool do I use to validate the template.yml to ensure it's correct from the Linux command line?

Comment: Please refer to the [official list](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-command%20line) of JSON Schema implementations. Currently, only [pajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pajv) supports YAML as input – though you can of course transform your YAML to JSON with one of several tools that can do that, and then use any validator that accepts JSON input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider using [yajsv](https://github.com/neilpa/yajsv) as it is covering both the YAML and JSON use cases.

The simpler way to install it is by downloading the proper [release](https://github.com/neilpa/yajsv/releases/tag/v1.4.1)

#### Linux `amd64` example:

###### To install it:

```bash
wget https://github.com/neilpa/yajsv/releases/download/v1.4.1/yajsv.linux.amd64
chmod +x ./yajsv.linux.amd64 # you may need to run it with root rights (aka sudo chm...)
```

Keep in mind that the URL may change soon so just copy the proper URL using your browser.

###### To validate ONE `Yaml` using a specific `JSON schema` you can use:

```bash
./yajsv.linux.amd64 -s /path/to/json/schema/direcotry/schema.json /path/to/yaml/data/direcotry/file.yml
```

-OR-

###### To validate MULTIPLE `Yaml`s using a specific `JSON schema` you can use:

```bash
./yajsv.linux.amd64 -s /path/to/json/schema/direcotry/schema.json -r /path/to/yaml/data/direcotry/file1.yml /path/to/yaml/data/direcotry/file2.yml /path/to/yaml/data/direcotry/file3.yml
```

You can use [yajsv GitHub](https://github.com/neilpa/yajsv) for more details.

#### Bonus:

If you are using [Nix package manager or NixOs](https://nixos.org/) you can test the [yajsv](https://github.com/neilpa/yajsv) first by using:

```bash
nix-shell -p yajsv
# test your yamls
exit # now yamls is not an existing command to your machine
```

If you want to install it:

```bash
# If you are running NixOS:
nix-env -iA nixos.yajsv

# If you are running other distributions:
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.yajsv
```